# Average metrics given by on_epoch_end seem wrong with tf.keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras, callback, tensorflow2.0

I was playing with `tf.keras` and was writing some basic custom callbacks, like the one given [here](https://keras.io/guides/writing_your_own_callbacks/#usage-of-logs-dict) to be more precise.

The loss metric given by the callbacks method `on_epoch_end` should be the average loss over all the minibatches, but I get the last loss registered, ie the loss of the last minibatch.

If you look on the [Tensorflow site](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_callback) in the section **Usage of logs dict**, by computing by hand you see that the loss given in the example with the method `on_epoch_end` **is** the average loss over all the batches of this epoch.

I tried without my custom callback, it doesn't change anything. Although
core code of [BaseLogger callback](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2b96f3662bd776e277f86997659e61046b56c315/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py#L758) said that you should get the average loss on epoch end, it's not what I get, I still get the loss of the last minibatch.

here's the code I wrote

```py
# import libs
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
import random

print(tf.__version__)
print(keras.__version__)

RANDOM_SEED = 42
random.seed(RANDOM_SEED)
tf.random.set_seed(RANDOM_SEED)

#dummy dataset
t_x = tf.random.uniform([30, 4], dtype=tf.float32)
t_y = tf.range(30)
ds_x = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(t_x)
ds_y = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(t_y)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds_x, ds_y))
ds = ds.batch(3)

# Custom callback
class LossCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):

    def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs):
        print(f'Batch {batch}, loss is {logs["loss"]:.2f}.\n')

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs):
        print(f'Avg loss on {epoch} is {logs["loss"]:.2f} \n')

cb = LossCallback()

# create dummy model
from tensorflow.keras import Model

input = Input(shape=(4,))
x = Dense(32)(input)
model = Model(input,x)

model.compile(loss = 'mean_absolute_error',
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD())

history = model.fit(ds,
                    epochs=1,
                    verbose=0,
                    callbacks=[cb])
```

and here's the result I got.

```
2.2.0
2.3.0-tf
Batch 0, loss is 1.03.

Batch 1, loss is 2.48.

Batch 2, loss is 3.95.

Batch 3, loss is 5.44.

Batch 4, loss is 6.93.

Batch 5, loss is 8.43.

Batch 6, loss is 9.93.

Batch 7, loss is 11.43.

Batch 8, loss is 12.93.

Batch 9, loss is 14.43.

Avg loss on 0 is 14.43
```

Getting rid of my custom callback and rerun

```py
history = model.fit(ds,
                    epochs=1)
```

didn't get me anywhere, since I still got the same loss.

I was on Google Colab when I was doing this.

Do you have any idea why I don't have the avg loss on epoch end ? Where did I go wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting the average loss in the end. What seems to be wrong is the loss per batch. Instead of returning the loss for the current batch, the callback in `on_train_batch_end` is printing the average loss. This seems to be an issue of TF: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39448

I did a little test, and Tensorflow 2.0.0 seems to present the expected behavior. Take a look at [this colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1WAQQxBi5llzvMRrUDw4mIj0l7VQnPBTC?usp=sharing) that uses your code with TF 2.0.0.

With TF 2.0.0, the output for your code was:

```
Batch 0, loss is 1.03.

      1/Unknown - 0s 438ms/step - loss: 1.0256
Batch 1, loss is 3.93.

      2/Unknown - 0s 222ms/step - loss: 2.4791
Batch 2, loss is 6.90.

      3/Unknown - 0s 149ms/step - loss: 3.9526
Batch 3, loss is 9.90.

      4/Unknown - 0s 113ms/step - loss: 5.4391
Batch 4, loss is 12.90.

      5/Unknown - 0s 91ms/step - loss: 6.9314 
Batch 5, loss is 15.92.

      6/Unknown - 0s 77ms/step - loss: 8.4295
Batch 6, loss is 18.91.

      7/Unknown - 0s 66ms/step - loss: 9.9273
Batch 7, loss is 21.94.

      8/Unknown - 0s 58ms/step - loss: 11.4284
Batch 8, loss is 24.93.

      9/Unknown - 0s 52ms/step - loss: 12.9280
Batch 9, loss is 27.90.

     10/Unknown - 0s 47ms/step - loss: 14.4251
Avg loss on 0 is 14.43 

10/10 [==============================] - 0s 49ms/step - loss: 14.4251
```

Comment: Ok, so what `on_train_batch_end` is showing is the running avg loss, which gives the avg loss at the end of the epoch, which isn't that great. I suppose that if I want to get the loss per minibtaches, I would have to make a custom train_step then, at least for now.

Comment: Yeah, if downgrading to a previous TF is not an option, I think this is the way to go for now :/

Answer (score 1):

In TensorFlow version 2.2 and newer, the loss provided to [`on_train_batch_end`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/Callback#on_train_batch_end) is now the average loss of all batches up until the current batch within the given epoch. This is also the case for additional metrics.

Fortunately, the loss for the current batch can be calculated from the average loss as follows:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback

class CustomCallback(Callback):
    ''' This callback converts the average loss (default behavior in TF>=2.2)
        into the loss for only the current batch.
    '''
    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs={}):
        self.previous_loss_sum = 0

    def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        # calculate loss of current batch:
        current_loss_sum =  (batch + 1) * logs['loss']
        current_loss = current_loss_sum - self.previous_loss_sum
        self.previous_loss_sum = current_loss_sum

        # use current_loss:
        # ...
```

This code can be added to any custom callback that needs the loss for the current batch instead of the average loss. You can make similar calculations for other metrics, as required by your specific callback.

Keep in mind, if you are using Tensorflow 1 or TensorFlow 2 version <= 2.1, then do not include this code in your callback, as in those versions the current loss is already provided, instead of the average loss. The values provided for metrics besides the loss are still averages in those older versions, so similar code could be useful for converting the average metric values into the metric values for just the current batch.